# echo json array VIA PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hellow, I have a `name` Column and This is My json:

```
[{"id":"26","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"30","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"31","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"32","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"33","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"34","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"40","answer":["Number 3"],"type":"2"}]
```

Why I Can't echo `answer` With This Code:

```
<?php 
  $jsonurl='C:\wamp64\www\library\json.json'; 
  $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);  
  $json_output = json_decode($json, true);        
  foreach ($json_output as $trend){         
   echo $trend['id']."\n";       //   OK
   //echo $trend['answer']."\n";   //  Error 
   echo $trend['type']."<br />";  //  OK
  }  
?>
```

Comment: start by looking into `json_decode()` to make this an php array and then work you way into sql. From there you have too many option to be able to answer your question specificly.

Comment: I Read `$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';` , But my Exaple is Defference, And I want to Select That json Column Automaticaly and I Have Radio Buttons too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is error in your `json.json` file in last line which is
`{"id":"40","answer":["Number":"3"],"type":"2"}]`

Second `$trend['answer']` is array you can not `echo` so you have to use `foreach` loop again like this

```
foreach($trend['answer'] as $ans){
      if(array_key_exists("Number",$ans)){  /* this is for last line */
        echo $ans['Number']."\n" ;
       } else {
        echo $ans['option']."\n";
        echo $ans['text']."\n" ;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Dear Friend, Then you mean i can't print `answer":["Number":"3"]` ? because this is descriptive Awnser, I mean, I have 2 Model Awnser `Radio Button` and `descriptive Awnser`

Comment: because `answer` is array so you have to use as array

Comment: if it's solve your answer than choose as correct answer , it will help me .

Comment: 1 More question, How Can I Read My jsons From a MySQL Column, Not a json File.

Comment: MySQL is relation database so one column for one value but you still want to use than use MySQL 5.7 for storing in json than use query according to it. read [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/) where you can see how query return output like object, array etc & use in it php

Comment: Thank you, I will Check That.

Comment: I like Something like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173353/echo-json-array-in-a-phpmyadmin-column-via-php)