# echo json array in a phpMyAdmin Column VIA PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hello I have JSON rows like This:

```
//THis is one of My Rows
     [{"id":"26","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"a"},
        {"id":"30","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"b"},
        {"id":"31","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"c"},
        {"id":"32","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"d"},
        {"id":"33","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"e"},
        {"id":"34","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"f"},
        {"id":"40","answer":["Number 3"],"type":"g"}]
```

How Can I echo `id` `answer` `type`,
and `db Name: array` `Table Name: user_survey_start` `JSON row Name: survey_answers`, This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","array");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

  //  $sql="SELECT  survey_answers->"$.id" AS `twitter` FROM user_survey_start";  
    $sql="SELECT  survey_answers FROM user_survey_start";


    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      // Fetch one and one row
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
        printf ("%s \n",$row[0]);
        }
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: And what is the issue? Also for last line in json`Number 3` will become string

Comment: I Like to Connect to my Table Column, And echo json rows Automaticaly, But Don't Know how can i do that,  Yes yes I like to fix That String too. Thank you

Comment: are you storing json in column name ` survey_answers` .

Comment: yes yes my column Name is **survey_answers**, i need make my json object to 3 part, in three column, can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I Need To Select My Primary Key

```
$sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey_start`";
```

Then Put Value To ID

```
$id[] = $data['id'];
```

After That

```
$sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
echo $sql1."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use json_decode() function to convert your json to php array(). After then you can iterate all data as your requirement.